# Code won't be executed in the injector but only in devtools console

Tags: javascript, console, devtools

I have some troubles regarding the code. It will be succesfully executed if pasted directly in DevConsole, while the same code used to be injected by a injector (addon) gives an error:
De code is: $("XXXXXXX").updateCaseOwnertoSelf();

If executed from the plugin it gives an error[image]

The same code pasted in DevTools Console goes OK - is there a plugin/addon which would paste the code in the console and execute it?
document.querySelector won't work so I use a dollar sign instead.

I may change the plugin but the problem is why there is a difference in the code execution between an addon and dev console.

Comment: Such a plugin would be an overkilling solution to this problem. Just make sure you load the script containing / define the function before it is called.

Comment: Most likely the jQuery plugin was not loaded when your injected script tried to call the method

Comment: Unfortunately it seems it is not a loading issue. Other scripts used in the same time work OK. Only this one refuses to be executed via the plugin and works only if done via Dev Console.

Comment: It has to be a timing issue (unless you've overridden `$.updateCaseOwnertoSelf` with  another type of value before this call is executed), have you used async/defer attributes in the script tags loading the libraries?

Comment: Honestly I am not aware of any of you mentioned. I just added a plugin, made some code (not related to this one) and it works.
I tried to add the new one and bah, the new chunk works only via Dev Console. I thought plugin just sends info to devconsole but it seems it works in other way.
There should be no difference between pasting the code in the console vs. plugin but yet it won't be accepted.

Comment: Take a look at the Network tab in the console, and check if the plug-in is loaded at all.

Comment: It is loaded, other chunks of code are being executed normally.